# Recursive function in Python to search items within lists

Tags: python, recursion, search

I am trying/required to write a recursive function where a True/False value is returned if an element is in a sorted list. I am required to not used the "in" keyword to get the answer. My code is below, I think I am close, but I can't seem to get the function to return a proper value:

```
def listSplitter(listToProcess, numToFind):
    lenOfList = len(listToProcess)

    if lenOfList == 1:
        if numToFind == listToProcess[0]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:

        if lenOfList % 2 == 0:
            list1 = listToProcess[0:int(lenOfList / 2)]
            list2 = listToProcess[int(lenOfList / 2):int(lenOfList)]

            if list1[-1] >= numToFind and list1[0] <= numToFind:
                return (list1, numToFind)
                #return
            elif list2[-1] >= numToFind and list2[0] <= numToFind:
                return listSplitter(list2, numToFind)
                #return
        else:
            list1 = listToProcess[0:int(lenOfList / 2)]
            list2 = listToProcess[int(lenOfList / 2):int(lenOfList)]

            if list1[-1] >= numToFind and list1[0] <= numToFind:
                return listSplitter(list1, numToFind)
                #return
            elif list2[-1] <= numToFind and list1[0] >= numToFind:
                return listSplitter(list2, numToFind)
                #return



def ordered_contains(S, x):
    return listSplitter(S,x)
    #result = listSplitter(S, x)
    #return result



A = [2, 16, 26, 32, 52, 71, 80, 88]

print("A contains 32: {}".format(ordered_contains(A, 32)))
print("A contains 7: {}".format(ordered_contains(A, 7)))
print("A contains -10: {}".format(ordered_contains(A, -10)))
print("\n(Did those results match the earlier example?)")
```

Here is the output:

```
A contains 32: ([2, 16, 26, 32], 32)
A contains 7: ([2, 16, 26, 32], 7)
A contains -10: None

(Did those results match the earlier example?)
```

What am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just use a while loop to iterate over each entry of the list

Comment: I have to use recursion, it's an assignment.

Comment: You seem to be missing the function call in this line: `return (list1, numToFind)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

1. Typos:

   - Line 16: `return (list1, numToFind)` -> `return listSplitter(list1, numToFind)`
   - Line 28: `elif list2[-1] <= numToFind and list1[0] >= numToFind:` -> `elif list2[-1] >= numToFind and list2[0] <= numToFind:` (If this isn't a typo, then I think it's logically incorrect)
2. If you correct the above typos, you will see that the code in 2 cases `if lenOfList% 2 == 0:` and `else` are the same. Hence, it is not necessary to divide these two cases.
3. Logic of

   ```py
   list1 = listToProcess[0:int(lenOfList / 2)]
   list2 = listToProcess[int(lenOfList / 2):int(lenOfList)]

   if list1[-1] >= numToFind and list1[0] <= numToFind:
       return listSplitter(list1, numToFind)
   elif list2[-1] >= numToFind and list2[0] <= numToFind:
       return listSplitter(list2, numToFind)
   ```

   will miss one case where `list1` and `list2` have 1 element and they are all different from `numToFind`. That's why the return is `None` in some cases. To handle this case just add `return False` at the end of the code above.

And here is the code after I correct the above problems:

```py
def listSplitter(listToProcess, numToFind):
    lenOfList = len(listToProcess)

    if lenOfList == 1:
        return numToFind == listToProcess[0]

    list1 = listToProcess[0:int(lenOfList / 2)]
    list2 = listToProcess[int(lenOfList / 2):int(lenOfList)]

    if list1[-1] >= numToFind and list1[0] <= numToFind:
        return listSplitter(list1, numToFind)
    elif list2[-1] >= numToFind and list2[0] <= numToFind:
        return listSplitter(list2, numToFind)
    
    return False


def ordered_contains(S, x):
    return listSplitter(S,x)


A = [2, 16, 26, 32, 52, 71, 80, 88]

print("A contains 32: {}".format(ordered_contains(A, 32)))
print("A contains 7: {}".format(ordered_contains(A, 7)))
print("A contains -10: {}".format(ordered_contains(A, -10)))
print("\n(Did those results match the earlier example?)")
```

Output:

```py
A contains 32: True
A contains 7: False
A contains -10: False

(Did those results match the earlier example?)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you made a mistake in line 16:

It shouldn't be `return (list1, numToFind)`.

It should be `return listSplitter(list1, numToFind)`.

Also, there is no need for `if lenOfList % 2 == 0:`. The length of the list being even or odd does not change your logic.

The complete code would look like

def listSplitter(listToProcess, numToFind):
lenOfList = len(listToProcess)

```
if lenOfList == 1:
    if numToFind == listToProcess[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
else:

    list1 = listToProcess[0:int(lenOfList / 2)]
    list2 = listToProcess[int(lenOfList / 2):int(lenOfList)]

    if list1[-1] >= numToFind and list1[0] <= numToFind:
        return listSplitter(list1, numToFind)
    elif list2[-1] >= numToFind and list2[0] <= numToFind:
        return listSplitter(list2, numToFind)
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

While the typo can be corrected, I tried the achieve the same in another way. I simulated a while loop throuogh recursion. It looks much simpler.

```
In [0]: def traverse(index, array, toCompare):
   ...:     if (array[index] == toCompare):
   ...:         print(f"Found {toCompare} at {index + 1} position of the list")
   ...:         return # You can return a boolean True value and the index here and print it outside.
   ...:     if (index != len(array) - 1):
   ...:         traverse(index + 1, array, toCompare)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print(f"Cannot find {toCompare} in list")
   ...:         return # You can return a boolean False value here and print it outside.
   ...:

In [1]: traverse(0, a, 77)
Cannot find 77 in list

In [2]: traverse(0, a, 88)
Found 88 at 8 position of the list

In [3]: a
Out[1]: [2, 16, 26, 32, 52, 71, 80, 88]
```

Just thought I would share this since it achieves the same in a simpler way.